# hdfs - ls: Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException:

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

I am trying to use the below to list my dirs in hdfs:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ hadoop fs -ls hdfs://127.0.0.1:50075/ 
ls: Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: 
Protocol    message end-group tag did not match expected tag.; 
Host Details : local host is: "ubuntu/127.0.0.1"; destination host is: "ubuntu":50075;
```

Here is my /etc/hosts file

```
127.0.0.1       ubuntu localhost
#127.0.1.1      ubuntu

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

How do I properly use hdfs:// to list my dirs?

I am using couldera 4.3 on ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 24):

HDFS is not running at 50075.
To check your hdfs port use the following command in linux

```
hdfs getconf -confKey fs.default.name
```

You will get the output something like

```
hdfs://hmaster:54310
```

And correct your URL accordingly

Comment: INFO Configuration.deprecation: fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS

Answer (score 7):

On your cloudera manager, check on the Name node for configuration item "NameNode Service RPC Port" OR "dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address". Add the same port number from there on the URL. And it should work fine. [image]

Answer (score 2):

Is your NN running on port `50075`? You actually don't have to do that if you just want to list down all the directories. Simply use `hadoop fs -ls /`. This will list all your directories under your root directory.

Answer (score 2):

In /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml

In place of **localhost**, use **0.0.0.0** i.e..

Change  `<value>hdfs://localhost:50075</value>` to

```
<value>hdfs://0.0.0.0:50075</value>
```

This solved the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your hostname?. The same name(ubuntu) should be there in your /etc/hostname file and /etc/hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your tcp port of NN is on 50075 which is defined in hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.nn1</name>
<value>r101072036.sqa.zmf:9000</value>
</property>
```

my problem is that I use http-address port to connect with NN, this cause the same exception as you.

the http port is also configured in hdfs-site.xml:

```
<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.http-address.nn1</name>
<value>r101072036.sqa.zmf:8000</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error arise because  of :

1. It is not able to contact with namenode
2. Namenode might be not running (you can check it by running `jps` command.)
3. kill what ever is running in that particular port

check what is running in particular port  by `netstat -tulpn | grep 8080`
and `kill -9 <PID>`

4. Restart the namenode