# Issue while creating Solr core on HDFS

Tags: solr, hdfs

I am trying to create solr core on HDFS in a stand alone instance (solr-5.3.0 and Hadoop 2.7). I have started the service like below,

```
$ bin/solr start -Dsolr.directoryFactory=HdfsDirectoryFactory -Dsolr.lock.type=hdfs -Dsolr.data.dir=hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp -Dsolr.updatelog=hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp -s solr-cores/core1
```

Waiting up to 30 seconds to see Solr running on port 8983 [/]
Started Solr server on port 8983 (pid=42277). Happy searching!

And trying to create core like below,

```
bin/solr create -c hdfsstarted -d /home/admin/HadoopTools/solr-5.3.0/server/solr/configsets/data_driven_schema_configs_hdfs/conf -n hdfsstarted
```

But getting below error:

> Setup new core instance directory:
>   /home/admin/HadoopTools/solr-5.3.0/solr-cores/core1/hdfsstarted
>
> Creating new core 'hdfsstarted' using command:
>   http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=hdfsstarted&instanceDir=hdfsstarted
>
> ERROR: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'hdfsstarted': Unable to create core [hdfsstarted] Caused by: Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag.

I have modified the solrconfig.xml like below,

```
<directoryFactory name="DirectoryFactory" class="solr.HdfsDirectoryFactory">
    <str name="solr.hdfs.home">hdfs://10.67.5.244:50070/tmp</str>
    <bool name="solr.hdfs.blockcache.enabled">true</bool>
    <int name="solr.hdfs.blockcache.slab.count">1</int>
    <bool name="solr.hdfs.blockcache.direct.memory.allocation">false</bool>
    <int name="solr.hdfs.blockcache.blocksperbank">16384</int>
    <bool name="solr.hdfs.blockcache.read.enabled">true</bool>
    <bool name="solr.hdfs.blockcache.write.enabled">false</bool>
    <bool name="solr.hdfs.nrtcachingdirectory.enable">true</bool>
    <int name="solr.hdfs.nrtcachingdirectory.maxmergesizemb">16</int>
    <int name="solr.hdfs.nrtcachingdirectory.maxcachedmb">192</int>
</directoryFactory>
<lockType>
   hdfs
</lockType>
```

Kindly let me know how to create core correctly in HDFS.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?  Seeing same error with a Solr->HDFS config using solr 5.2.1 and hdp 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag.

This error happens because you are using incorrect HDFS port. See [hdfs - ls: Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException:](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16372997/2417043) .

Here you need to change port from 50070 (which looks like NameNode web ui port) to 8020 or whatever port you are using as NameNode RPC port:

```
<str name="solr.hdfs.home">hdfs://10.67.5.244:50070/tmp</str>
```